# Radiobuttons to get the functionality of tabs

Tags: android, radio-button, android-tabhost

### I am looking at something similar to tab widget.

---

**`Is it possible to use multiple buttons on same form and get the look and feel of a tab widget?`**

- Basically, on a click of a button, a new form should be opened to
  fill up some values in same.

**Functionality like a Tabhost**

- If true how to go for it
- I looked many places and googled stuff ... I couldn't get a proper
  tutorial of any good source of information

Would be better radio buttons can be used !

I am a new bie so ... please go easy on me with answers :)

Comment: I am also looking for something similar !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short reply: you can implement the functionality using the Fragments, see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for details.
Basically, you have to declare a layout like the one below

```
   (Vertical LinearLayout)
+---------------------------+
|      |      |      |      |
|  B1  |  B2  |  B3  |  B4  |  (LinearLayout with 4 Buttons)
|      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|       FRAGMENTS           |
|                           | (FrameLayout matching the parent)
|          AREA             |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
|                           |
+---------------------------+
```

B1, B2, B3 and B4 are Buttons (or checkboxes, or whatever your GUI use to select the current view). Given a default view (Fragment) to be shown, each time you press a Button you change the Fragment in the Fragment area (resetting the Fragments back stack).

Answer (score 0):

Have a linear layout with a button and a ViewPager, you can add a layout to each view of ViewPager, and based on the click move to that view of the ViewPager.

Refer to: [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)